# Pointwise convergence of a series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Describe the set of all points $x$ where the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^n/(1+x^n)$ pointwise converges. Does it uniformly converge on $[3,5]$?

Where to start. Usually I fix $x$ and take it out of sum but I don't think I can do that here.

---

*(Added from a now-deleted answer.)*

I found that the set of points x is all x such that |x|>1 for pointwise convergence. But I don't understand how comparing it to that series shows uniform covergence. How is (2/x^n) uniformly convergent and what is the comparison?

Comment: Hint: we have $x\geq 3$ on this interval.

Comment: Just compare it to $\sum (2/x)^n$, and note that the latter converges on $[3,5]$

Answer (score 1):

For every $x>2$ we have
$$
0<\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^n}{1+x^n}\le \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^n}{x^n}=\frac{1}{1-2/x}=\frac{x}{x-2}.
$$
Therefore the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^n}{1+x^n}$ converges for every $x>2$.

Answer (score 0):

> I found that the set of points x is all x such that |x|>1 for pointwise convergence

This is incorrect. For example, when $x=1.5$, the terms of the series grow indefinitely, so it certainly is not convergent.

You need $|x|>2$ for pointwise convergence: see Mercy's answer.

For uniform convergence on $[3,5]$, estimate the $n$th term by $(2/3)^n$ and use the Weierstrass M-test.